# Redmine install issue with bin/rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redhat, redmine, bin

```
[redmine@uhso919 redmine]$ /usr/local/bin/ruby bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
3: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2: from /var/www/redmine/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

I've searched the web with no solution. Any idea what is going on with attempting to install Redmine.

I am on **Red Hat 7.4 Ruby 2.5.0p0** and it's all command-line through Putty. 
I am using the [set of directions here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Install_Redmine_34_on_RHEL74).

Comment: could you try installing `bundler`? `gem install bundler` and then starting the server?

Comment: Same result....

Comment: can you try `/usr/local/bin/ruby bundle exec bin/rails server ...`